# AngularJS UI Router - change url without reloading state and Change data only

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, user-interface, routes

I'm using Angular UI Router and would like to reload the current state and refresh all data / re-run the controllers for the current state and it's parent.

```
.state('StateData', {
                    url: '/:cityName/StateData',
                    templateUrl: BASE_URL + '/partials/StateData/StateDataItems.html',
                    controller: 'StateDataController',
                   }
                }).
.state('home', {
                    url: '/:CityName',
                    controller: 'CityName',
                    templateUrl: BASE_URL + '/partials/CityName/cityname.html',
             });
```

Now I am using in commom controller file, calling below mentioned function after popup colse

```
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
```

**ISSUE:** I am unable to change SITE URL;

```
www.site.com/CITYNAME/citydata
```

**CITYNAME** : it will be dynamically change.

So url will

```
www.site.com/NY/citydata
```

or

```
www.site.com/DC/citydata
```

but page should not be refreshed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the CityName params in the `$state` like

```
$state.go($state.current.name, {CityName : 'NY'}, {reload: true});
```

Comment: data is changing but url is not.

Comment: `$state.current` is an object you need to give the name of the state